# JS image detect won't addClass for image if X = width and X =height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script below. What is currently does, for `each` time the `'mobile-carousel-container'` loads an `'item`' it finds the `div` with the classname of `'item'` ---  `if` 'item' `hasClass` of '`active'` it then applies specific class based to the `image` if is a specific `width and height.` 
The problem I am running into, is the DOM I know for some reach is not checking each 'item' and so it finds the one with the current state of 'active' and simply applies it -- I want it to do it EVERYTIME an images slides through the carousel -- not just that one instance.

Thoughts?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xdjpyr

```
// everytime this carousel loads do this            
$('.mobile-carousel-container').each(function() {
  // find the carousel item -- declare variable
  var imgs = $('.item');
  // for each item function do this --
  imgs.each(function() {
    // if item hasClass 'active' -- do this
    if ($(imgs).hasClass('active')) {
      // img is this instance 
      var img = $(this);
      // check ALL ifs if any dimensions match image dimensions

      // if this addClass 'top'
      if (img.width() == 320 && img.height() == 50 || // 300 x 250
        img.width() == 300 && img.height() == 100 || // 300 x 100
        img.width() == 300 && img.height() == 50 || // 300 x 50
        img.width() == 250 && img.height() == 250 || // 250 x 250
        img.width() == 728 && img.height() == 90 || // 729 x 90
        img.width() == 468 && img.height() == 60 || // 468 x 60
        img.width() == 240 && img.height() == 400 || // 240 x 400
        img.width() == 180 && img.height() == 150 || // 180 x 150
        img.width() == 125 && img.height() == 125 || // 125 x 125
        img.width() == 234 && img.height() == 60 || // 234 x 60
        img.width() == 120 && img.height() == 60) // 120 x 60
      {
        img.addClass('top');
      }
      // if this addClass 'bottom'
      if (img.width() == 930 && img.height() == 180 || // 930 x 180
        img.width() == 336 && img.height() == 280 || // 336 x 280
        img.width() == 234 && img.height() == 60) // 234 x 60
      {
        img.addClass('bottom');
      }
      // if this addClass 'middle'
      if (img.width() == 300 && img.height() == 250) // 300 x 250
      {
        img.addClass('middle');
      }
      // if this addClass 'right'
      if (img.width() == 300 && img.height() == 250 || // 300 x 250
        img.width() == 120 && img.height() == 600 || // 120 x 600
        img.width() == 160 && img.height() == 600) // 600 x 160 
      {
        img.addClass('right');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("#carousel-container-mobile, #carousel-container-desktop").on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
      $('.item').each(function() {
          var img = $('img', this);
          if (img.width() == 320 && img.height() == 50 || // 300 x 250
            img.width() == 300 && img.height() == 100 || // 300 x 100
            img.width() == 300 && img.height() == 50 || // 300 x 50
            img.width() == 250 && img.height() == 250 || // 250 x 250
            img.width() == 728 && img.height() == 90 || // 729 x 90
            img.width() == 468 && img.height() == 60 || // 468 x 60
            img.width() == 240 && img.height() == 400 || // 240 x 400
            img.width() == 180 && img.height() == 150 || // 180 x 150
            img.width() == 125 && img.height() == 125 || // 125 x 125
            img.width() == 234 && img.height() == 60 || // 234 x 60
            img.width() == 120 && img.height() == 60) // 120 x 60
          {
            img.addClass('top');
          }
          if (img.width() == 930 && img.height() == 180 || // 930 x 180
            img.width() == 336 && img.height() == 280 || // 336 x 280
            img.width() == 234 && img.height() == 60) // 234 x 60
          {
            img.addClass('bottom');
          }
          if (img.width() == 300 && img.height() == 250) // 300 x 250
          {
            img.addClass('middle');
          }
          if (img.width() == 300 && img.height() == 250 || // 300 x 250
            img.width() == 120 && img.height() == 600 || // 120 x 600
            img.width() == 160 && img.height() == 600) // 600 x 160
          {
            img.addClass('right');
        }
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's only going to hit the 'active' photo because of line 8:

```
if ($(imgs).hasClass('active'))
```

It will only do it on the first load. You'll need something like an on click trigger if you want it to repeat and do it again on an event.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: That's what 'each' is for.  An onClick function is redundant here.

Comment: each is an iterator. Once the page loads the first time, it iterates through all the items, and finds the 'active' class. Then it finishes. When you switch the 'active' class, it doesn't fire this function again.  If you had an .on "click" or however the slide is activated trigger this function -- it'll iterate over each item again.

Comment: Spencer Rohan is right here. You need to understand .each(). It does not do, what your comments suggest.

Comment: Remove if ($(imgs).hasClass('active')) -- does this do what you want?

Comment: No, I got it, the each function should of been set to 'item' and the window.load replaced with onslide.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgs = $('.item');
  imgs.each(function() {
    if ($(imgs).hasClass('active')) {
      var img = $(this);
```

Here variable `img` is `div.item`, whose width will be by default, the width of the screen. If you want to get width of image, you will have to do:

```
      var img = $('img', this);
```

Also make sure images are `loaded` before you try to get the `width` and `height` of image. You can wrap the whole code inside `$(window).load()` to make sure your code is run after all images are completely loaded.

```
var dimensionsArray = ["300 x 250", "300 x 100", "300 x 50", 
                      "250 x 250", "729 x 90", "468 x 60","240 x 400", 
                      "180 x 150", "125 x 125", "234 x 60", "120 x 60"];
if (dimensionsArray.indexOf(img.width() +" x "+ img.height()) !== -1)
{
  img.addClass('top');
}
```

Comment: I stored all images into an array and pulled in through 'indexOf' but it won't even add the class if there is an element that has a class of 'active' whereas before it would add the class but for only 1 static image. Updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xdjpyr

Answer (score 0):

Your comments do not describe, what your code actually does. Your first codeline, for instance,

```
// everytime this carousel loads do this            
$('.mobile-carousel-container').each(function() {
```

Does not happen every time the carousel loads. It happens once, when the page is loaded, and all it does is iterate through the images. Because of line 8:

```
if ($(imgs).hasClass('active')) {
```

... the only affected image will be the one image, that is active, when the page is loaded (as Spencer Rohan pointed out already). You need to learn, how .each() works: http://api.jquery.com/each/

EDIT:
Also, the word 'load' might be misunderstood in your comments. Does the carousel really 'load' the images, when displaying them? Would be a little odd. If all the images are, indeed, 'loaded' at page load and the carousel simply gives them display:block and display:none (or something similar) when showing them, you could skip line 8 and apply the classes to all the images at page load.

Comment: each() worked just fine, the problem was I was invoking the wrong div. You are correct, that it will only load that div once. So each() had to bet set to the element that the DOM will load everytime 'item'. if ($(imgs).hasClass('active')) for that one image that is loaded in the DOM, but will work if I specify it to do it to each one which I hadn't before.