# Why won't function match width and height from varying arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I had the following  [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994882/js-image-detect-wont-addclass-for-image-if-x-width-and-x-height/35998900#35998900) previously and it was quite imploded with redundant repeated variables. So I wanted to improve it and stored the images into arrays. However, even with the same contextual markup of the previous script it will not detect the image values from the array and match it to the `item`. I'm not sure why. I set each item to check for instances of varying image sizes and then do what the `if` states.

[Working fiddle (non-working script):](http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/6/)

[Working fiddle: (working script):](http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/7/)

Am I not expressing the correct values of the array. I feel I am overthinking and overlooking something small. But I'm honestly stumped.

```
var top_horizontalvert_mobile = ['320 x 50', '300 x 100', '300 x 50', '250 x 250', '120 x 60', '240 x 400', '180 x 150', '125 x 125'];
var top_horizontal_desktop = ['729 x 90', '468 x 60'];                                                                   
var bottom_horizontal_desktop = ['930 x 180', '336 x 280'];                             
var bottom_vert_mobile = ['234 x 60'];
var middle_vert_mobile = ['300 x 250'];
var right_vert_desktop = ['120 x 600', '160 x 600'];
$("#carousel-container-mobile, #carousel-container-desktop").on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
      var imgs = $('.item');
      var w = $(img).width();
      var h = $(img).height();
      var img = $('img', this);
      if (w == top_horizontalvert_mobile && h == top_horizontalvert_mobile) {
         img.addClass('top, smaller-img');
      }
      if (w == top_horizontal_desktop && h == top_horizontal_desktop) {
         img.addClass('top, larger-img');
      }
      if (w == bottom_vert_mobile && h == bottom_vert_mobile) {2
         img.addClass('bottom, smaller-img');
      }
      if (w == bottom_horizontal_desktop && h == bottom_horizontal_desktop) {
         img.addClass('bottom, larger-img');
      }
      if (w == middle_vert_mobile && h == middle_vert_mobile) {
         img.addClass('middle, smaller-img');
      }
      if (w == right_vert_desktop && h == right_vert_desktop) {
         img.addClass('right, smaller-img');
      }
      if (w == middle_vert_mobile && h == middle_vert_mobile) {
         img.addClass('right, smaller-img');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: If the elements are hidden the height and width of the hidden elements will be junk values. junk in the sense not a correct value.

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between your two scripts is how you are comparing values.

In the working script, you are directly comparing numbers:

`if (img.width() == 320 && img.height() == 50)`

In the non-working script, you are actually comparing a number with an array.

`if (w == top_horizontalvert_mobile)`

which if we swapped to the more literal values:

`if (img.width() == ['320 x 50', '300 x 100', '300 x 50', '250 x 250', '120 x 60', '240 x 400', '180 x 150', '125 x 125']`

And there will never be a condition where a number will an array since arrays are a different data type.

Based on what I'm seeing, you are trying to compare each width and height to each value in the array, but that would require the following minimum steps:

1. Convert your array into a multi-dimensional array of numbers since keeping it as a string would require you to parse out the data (which is more work than necessary. So instead of `[320 x 50', '300 x 100' ...]`, you'd have [[320, 50], [300, 100] ...]`
2. Iterate through each value of the array with a for loop so you can do your comparisons. See [Codecademy's tutorial on for loops](https://www.codecademy.com/de/courses/javascript-beginner-en-NhsaT/0/1) to learn more.

Let me know if you have any other questions!

As an aside though, after reviewing your working script and looking for what you're trying to do, it seems you are trying to apply different styles based on the image size through jQuery. Is there a reason why you are not just applying the classes directly to the images themselves since you seem to have very specific requirements on the image sizes?